# Seeking Probability Function Invariant under Normal Gaussian Convolution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, convolution, gaussian-integral

I'm currently working on a problem where I need to find a probability function,
$P(x)$, that remains unchanged after a normal Gaussian convolution. Specifically, the function should satisfy the following integral equation:
$$P(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}}P(t)dt$$
And should be $1\geq P(x) \geq 0$ for any $x$.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Could someone guide me?

Comment: If we denote by $\varphi$ the standard Gaussian density, then your question amounts to finding a function $P$ such that $P = P*\varphi$ where $*$ is the convolution. Taking the Fourier transform, we get $\widehat{P} = \widehat{P} \widehat{\varphi}$. If we use the unitary Fourier transform, i.e. normalized by $\sqrt{2\pi}$, then $\widehat{\varphi} = \varphi$. So the solution $P$ has to be such that $\widehat{P} = \widehat{P}\varphi$ and I think the only function that satisfies this is $P \equiv 0$ and consequently no probability distribution satisfies this equality.

Comment: @Shiva Imagine a random walk agent that each time steps from a sample of normal distribution. If we start at point zero and random walk till infinity, lets define the probability of ever reaching the point $x$ as $P(x)$. Then it is easy to show that this equation should held for it: $$P(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}}P(t)dt$$